# How to sell a ship

Tags: no-mans-sky

At this point, I've acquired several ships including a few junkers.  If I got one of those junk ships flying, could I take it somewhere and sell it for units? Or am I stuck with it for the rest of the game?

My best idea so far is to get it flying and trade it for another.  But that will still cost credits, not make credits.

If it matters, I'm not very far on the plot.  I haven't left the star system yet.

Comment: Newer question: [How to break old or unwanted ships down to their parts?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361723/30863)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my own answer but I don't like it.  We're limited to just *6* ships.  When you hit that limit, you can only exchange your existing ships.  So, they can't be sold but they can still be traded up for better ships.

Comment: Does this limit also apply if you own a Freighter?

Comment: @DavidYell, according to the wiki, yes.