# How to break old or unwanted ships down to their parts?

Tags: no-mans-sky

With the new Synthesis update we can now dismantle no more wanted [starships](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Starship). But how exactly do we do that?

I have found an old broken - not yet flying ship - on a new planet. It is possible to summon this ship to my base. But not to my freighter.

Do I have to repair the starship first to the point where I can fly it to the next space station and then dismantle it at the "Starship Outfitting Terminal"?

Or do you know another way to dismantle such a no more needed starship?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take it to any space station you will find a ship outfitters next to where the appearance modifier is normally located.

In order to get it to a space station you'll need to repair the [Launch Thruster](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Launch_Thruster) and [Pulse Engine](https://nomanssky.gamepedia.com/Pulse_Engine).

You'll be given the option to upgrade it or break it down. If you're lucky when breaking it down you'll be given a ship augmentation which you can use to expand the storage/technology capacity of another ship.

Once you have broken your ship down, 1 of your other ships will appear in the stations docking bay (from experience which ship you get from your collection seems to be random).